# Terminal commands to color differences between two files

Tags: command-line, bash, command-line-arguments

I have two text files that I want to highlight the differences of in a red color for testing purposes. I am feeding a series of inputs into something.py file and outputting its results to out.txt.

```
cat test3.txt | python3 something.py > out.txt
```

I have an expected.txt file that I want to compare to with out.txt and highlight differences in red.

Here's exactly what I have so far:

```
#! usr/bin/bash
GREEN=$'\e[0;32m'

printf "\n${GREEN}--- Test 1 ---${NC}\n"
cat test3.txt | python3 something.py
```

I am on a mac. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to investigate [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta). It's easily installed with Homebrew.

Comment: Command `diff` can be used with a `--color` argument.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, `diff` can do this for you

```
diff out.txt expected.txt —-color
```

[image]